# How to handle differently sized images when converting a set of images into a video and vice versa with OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

Here I'm trying to make a converter which can convert a set of images into a video file and vice versa.

When creating such a video, a fixed frame size is needed to be defined. I have defined the frame size as the size of the first uploaded image. But as the uploaded images have different sizes, this will give an error as it may differ from the defined frame size. Note that I want my extracted images from the video file to be the same dimensions as the original image I uploaded so I cannot resize the image to the frame size.

```
import cv2

image_list = ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg", "img4.jpg", "img5.jpg"]

# Sets the method of compression of the video file
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
output_file = "output.mp4"
fps = 1

# Sets the frame size of the video to the size of the first image
first_image = cv2.imread(image_list[0])
frame_size = (first_image.shape[1], first_image.shape[0])

video = cv2.VideoWriter(output_file, codec, fps, frame_size)

for image_path in image_list:
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    video.write(image)

video.release()
```

I essentially want this. A video can be created using a set of images. This set of images can be of different sizes. (Then for the second part, the images can be extracted from the video. These images should be of their original sizes)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: How about storing the image dimensions in a list and later resizing the image to its original dimensions based on the frame number?

Comment: Instead of resizing using `cv2.resize`, you may add padding to the smaller images, so all images have a common (larger) resolution. Restoring the images from the video is not trivial (unless saving the sizes of all the original frames in a separate file, or adding this data as metadata to the MP4 file [somehow]). You may also try using padding color that is unique enough, and can be identified and removed later (but the video compression is going to modify the padding color a little bit).

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine that could work :)